# Hyperbolic Spaces Embedded in Euclidean Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I want an embedding of the hyperbolic space of dimension $n$, or the manifold $\mathbb{H}^n$ in a Euclidean space of some dimension.

I know this can be embedded in the Minkowski space and this can not be done for $\mathbb{E}^3$.

A reference would do. Also, $n=2$ is my concern. But I guess it is not that hard to generalize this to higher dimensions.

Comment: [This thesis](http://davidbrander.org/penn.pdf) from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/497907/265452) is a good start.