# Rectangles in Hyperbolic geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, rectangles

[This](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Mihai/section5.html) says rectangles don't exist in hyperbolic geometry. But according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119728/description-of-model-of-euclidean-geometry-found-in-the-hyperbolic-plane) you can model the euclidean plane in Hyperbolic geometry. Wondering why you can't model the rectangle, I thought if you can do euclidean geometry in 2d plane you can get rectangle. The question is how to get (or introduce something to get) a rectangle in hyperbolic 2d plane.

Comment: I suppose you could say that the Poincare disc model is a model of the hyperbolic plane in the Euclidean plane. But that doesn't mean there are Euclidean triangles with angle sum $<\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful with your definitions. Yes, a [Horosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horosphere) in Hyperbolic 3 space is an isometric model of the Euclidean plane, but the euclidean lines in this model are **not** hyperbolic lines. Thus, any model of a euclidean rectangle has four right angles but its sides are **not** hyperbolic lines, and therefore it is **not** a hyperbolic rectangle. See my answer to the recent [MSE question 3119728](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3119728) "Description of Model of Euclidean Geometry found in the Hyperbolic Plane".

The same kind of situation arises in using a sphere in Euclidean 3 space as a model of the elliptic plane. The elliptic lines in the model are great circles of the sphere and are **not** euclidean lines.